# Please explain the expression in this Tcl if statement

Tags: tcl

I've not seen a Tcl if {expression} like the one below. I need help understanding
$TVAR(h_flows,comm,current_stage)

Thanks!!

```
if {$TVAR(h_flows,comm,current_stage) == "300_start"} {  
   puts "...
```

Answer (score 2):

It just tests if that particular array element's value is equal to the given string (And it really should be using `eq`, not `==`, to force string comparison).

If you're not familiar with Tcl arrays, see [this introduction](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/array) in the Tcler's Wiki.

Comment: And also the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `$TVAR(h_flows,comm,current_stage)` is just a read (because `$`) from the `h_flows,comm,current_stage` element of the `TVAR` array. Yes, the name of that element has commas in it, and some people use that to create compound keys, but the array itself (and Tcl) doesn't care.